# Laravel Doctrine ordering a paginated result

Tags: php, laravel, doctrine-orm

I'm new to Doctrine and I've been starting to use it for a personal project. I'm using the laravel-doctrine libraries to get it working with laravel.

Unfortunately, when I attempt to order a paginated query I see the following error:

```
An exception occurred while executing 'SELECT DISTINCT id_0 FROM (SELECT 
t0_.id AS id_0, t0_.title AS title_1, t0_.slug AS slug_2, t0_.views AS  
views_3, t0_.replies AS replies_4, t0_.created_at AS created_at_5,  
t0_.updated_at AS updated_at_6, p1_.id AS id_7, p1_.body AS body_8,  
p1_.created_at AS created_at_9, p1_.updated_at AS updated_at_10,  
p1_.deleted_at AS deleted_at_11, c2_.id AS id_12, c2_.name AS name_13,  
c2_.slug AS slug_14, c2_.created_at AS created_at_15, c2_.updated_at AS  
updated_at_16 FROM topics t0_ LEFT JOIN posts p1_ ON t0_.id = p1_.topic_id  
LEFT JOIN categories c2_ ON t0_.category_id = c2_.id) dctrn_result ORDER BY  
created_at_5 ASC LIMIT 10 OFFSET 0':

SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 3065 Expression #1 of ORDER BY clause is not  
in SELECT list, references column 'dctrn_result.created_at_5' which is not  
in SELECT list; this is incompatible with DISTINCT
```

The actual code that causes this error is as follows:

```
    public function findAll($results = 10, $pageName = 'page') {
        $query = $this->createQueryBuilder('t')
            ->select('t', 'f', 'c')
            ->leftJoin('t.first', 'f', 'ON')
            ->leftJoin('t.category', 'c', 'ON')
            ->orderBy('t.createdAt', 'asc')
            ->getQuery();

        return $this->paginate($query, $results, $pageName);
    }
```

I am trying to select a list of topics, with their category and first post all while ordered by the topic created_at date.

I've spent some time looking into this but as of yet have been unable to figure out what's going on, is there another way I should be doing this or is my code incorrect?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It turns out that the fourth argument for `paginate()` is causing this issue, it defaults to `true` but setting it to `false` caused this to start working again.

```
 public function paginate(Query $query, $perPage, $pageName = 'page', $fetchJoinCollection = true)
```

Simply set `$fetchJoinCollection` to false. I'm uncertain as to exactly why, but it works for now.

Comment: I have the exact same error as you but mine has left join, has to turn the `$fetchJoinCollection` to be true. This solution doesn't work for me.

Answer (score 0):

According to this http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/tutorials/pagination.html Doctrine does 3 steps to calculate the correct count:

1. Perform a Count query using DISTINCT keyword.
2. Perform a Limit Subquery with DISTINCT to find all ids of the entity in from on the current page.
3. Perform a WHERE IN query to get all results for the current page.

I think there is a bug in this when the ORDER BY clause is appended outside of the Subquery instead of inside, which generates the SQL error. In the document, at the bottom, they do say that setting the fetchJoinCollection = false will skip 1 step. This probably walk around the issue.

I hope that they'll fix this in the future release.